# Poor query performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, index-tuning, index-statistics, parameter

We have a large (10,000+ lines) procedure that typically runs in 0.5-6.0 seconds depending on how much data it has to work with. Over the past month or so it has started taking 30+ seconds after we do a statistics update with FULLSCAN. When it slows down, a sp_recompile "fixes" the issue, until the nightly statistics job runs again.

By comparing the slow and fast execution plans, I have narrowed it down to a specific table/index. When it runs slow it is estimating ~300 rows will be returned from a specific index, when it runs fast it estimates 1 row. When it runs slow it uses a Table Spool after doing a seek on the index, when it runs fast it doesn't do the Table Spool.

Using DBSS SHOW_STATISTICS, I graphed out the index histogram in excel. I would normally expect the graph to be more "rolling hills", but instead, it looks like a mountain, the highest point being 2x-3x higher than most other values on the graph.

[image: Index Histogram]

If I update statistics on it, without FULLSCAN, it looks more normal. If I then run it with FULLSCAN again it looks like I described above.

This feels like a parameter sniffing issue, and specifically related to the (seemingly) weird index distribution above.

The proc takes in a table valued parameter, can parameter sniffing occur on a table valued parameter?

EDIT: The proc also takes 12 other parameters, some of which are optional, two of which are a start and end date.

Is the histogram odd, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

I am certainly comfortable trying to adjust the query and/or try to adjust my indexing. If that is the fix that is great, at that point my question is more about the skewed histogram.

I should mention that this is a PK IDENTITY clustered index. We have two systems that talk to each other, one a legacy system, one a new home-grown system. Both systems store similar data. To keep them in sync the PK on this table in the new system is incremented when things are added to the old system, even if the data doesn't come over (a RESEED is done). So there could be some gaps in the numbering in this column. Records are rarely, if ever, deleted.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. I am more than happy to gather/include more info.

Comment: Is the **only** parameter to the procedure a TVP or are there other params too?

Comment: Edited to answer your question.

Comment: If you look at slow and fast plan XML would the difference be explicable by different `ParameterCompiledValue` for these other params?

Comment: Are you able to manually affect the table spool by using a table variable or temporary table?

Comment: The date range it compiled with is dramatically narrower (5 days instead of 31). For the majority of calls this proc will be ran for a month. I could try adding a recompile hint to that specific statement.

Comment: Jon - I don't think the Table Spool would exist at all if the query weren't using a plan for a much narrower date range.

Comment: I think I may go the "local variable" route to get rid of the parameter sniffing trouble. I just did a test and the performance of the proc seems unchanged (in it's faster state). Though I am still interested in HOW SQL determines the layout of the statistics histogram, it seems odd to have so much lumped together in a single step.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was to try to do the table spool yourself using a table variable or temp table instead of relying on the optimizer to do it for you.

Comment: Jon - I could do that, but I fear that the operation of setting up the temp table and populating it would be too expensive in a majority of the use cases. We are going to go with the local variable option for now, and maybe try to clean up the where clause to see if we can avoid spooling.

Comment: That definitely seems like an odd distribution for an identity column. I was just reading this article, and was wondering if you can elaborate on what you are seeing for estimated vs. actual on these two plans? > http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2013/04/18/understanding-sql-server-cardinality-estimations-by-charting-histogram-to-actual-values.aspx

Comment: Just to be clear: what is the graph of exactly? `RANGE_HI_KEY` on the x-axis presumably, but what is on the y-axis? `EQ_ROWS`? `RANGE_ROWS`? The sum of those?

Comment: I've only just glanced at this thread, so I might well be talking rubbish, but is the table by any chance associated with a database snapshot? If so you might try removing the snapshot. We had a problem just like this about 7 years ago, and it turned out that the snapshot was slugging performance whenever an update took place in the table.

Comment: Paul - I can't remember now, sorry. 

Glyn - This ended up being related to parameter sniffing. It just so happened that some oddly formed versions of this query were being executed RIGHT AFTER the stats were rebuilt. So the cached plan was not representative of the majority of the calls. I used the trick of copying the date parameters to local variables and this is working just fine, with little to no impact on performance.

Answer (score 3):

This ended up being related to parameter sniffing. It just so happened that some oddly formed versions of this query were being executed RIGHT AFTER the stats were rebuilt. So the cached plan was not representative of the majority of the calls. I used the trick of copying the date parameters to local variables and this is working just fine, with little to no impact on performance. This doesn't answer why the histogram looks so "off", but it does explain my performance issues.